# expo android build failed grandle how can I fix this?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to build an apk with expo and get this error:

```
[stderr] 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.

[stderr] 

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

[stderr] 

> Compilation error. See log for more details

[stderr] 

* Try:

[stderr] 

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I dont understand nothing in this error, does anyone have an idea what it could be the error ?

................................................................................................

Comment: Try installing the latest version of `expo-splash-screen` via `expo install expo-splash-screen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already run into this ... Which expo version are you on ?

`explo-splash-screen` had a known bug in v49.0.0 just upgrade to expo@latest ( currently expo@49.0.8 )

This [FIX](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/23747) fixed it

`npm i expo@49.0.8`

It should get rid of the build error